# can't use Terminal in VS Code with Python

Tags: python, terminal

I have installed VS Code, Python, and Python extension.

i'm following the Microsoft instructions, but for some reason i cant do - 
Python filename.py

in the terminal, the path is correct.

it doesn't run the file

and when  i do run it add the " & " in the beginning.

now i want to create a virtual folder and there is no respond from the terminal.

where did i go wrong?
the installation process? does it matter if i'm administrator?
thanks you for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WB73.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

my mistake was in the installation process.
before installing it ask you "add python to PATH" - check that box!

in this video, at 3:13
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnhQBUEpWlg